# How do I add prices to Products report?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, pricebook, product

A colleague wants a list of all products in his area and their prices. I can list the products but cannot seem to create a report that includes the prices listed / the price book. Is there no Price book product report or a way I can say

Product A is listed for price $, £, Euro and is active.

Really do not even know where to start with coding so looking for an easy way out if possible?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some reports were hidden - See below image to resolve.
Tick "Select Report Types to Hide" - If there is an X next to the report it is hidden, click it to show and then have access to the report.

[image: Hidden Report Types]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Reports > Create New Report > Price Books, Products and Assets, Price Book with Products. From there, you can see the Product, its cost per currency, and the Price Book it's in.

Comment: I thought that would be the case as well, I do not have the Price book with products report on my list... -- Added a screen shot above

Comment: @PaulRogers That's interesting. Are you a system administrator? There may be certain permissions you're lacking. I've never thought too hard about this, because I'm usually the admin wherever I am (comes with being popular, I guess?), but I'd imagine you have to have something like Manage Price Books or perhaps Modify All Data. Unlike most other features in salesforce, it's never quite clear which permissions you need to run a specific report. If you're not an admin, try asking your friendly admin for a report. Other than that, you might need to contact support.

Comment: Hey, Figured it out - some one had hidden the report type - i've just taken over as a Salesforce Admin for a company - Previous to me they had another admin who was self taught and worked here for 8 years but left without giving a hand over so things are all over the show. Thanks for your advice. Very impressed with your profile as well - 11 Years !! High 5 my man.

Comment: @PaulRogers It's a great platform, constantly evolving, and always a new challenge. It's been the most enjoyable decade of my life so far, and definitely rewarding. Hopefully, you'll feel the same way. I wouldn't trade the last decade of what I've done for anything.

Comment: Love to hear your passion - I was introduced to Salesforce about 2 years ago as a user in a customer service team - Absolutely fell in love with how open and customizable it is and now just about to sit my ADM201 exam. -- Side question for you if you dont mind - Can I add the Product ID to the products with pricebook report? Kind of a pointless report if I cannot mass change with the data loader.

Comment: @PaulRogers Did you want to update the price information, or the product itself? It seems odd, the built-in report doesn't allow the Id fields to be queried, but I just added formulas to the objects with simply "Id" as the formula type, and then I could get those. You might also just try creating a custom report type in Setup.

Comment: I tried custom report type but I cannot get a report type to include Products & pricebooks. I basically need to send a report to one of the directors showing all products that are active, what prices they are (Multiple pricebooks & Currencies) - He then wants me to deactivate a load of them and change the price on a load of others but I dont think there is an easy way to do this even with the data loader. Stupid that SF does not allow ID in standard reports of this nature

Comment: @PaulRogers Oh, the data loader would be preferable. You could just do something like "SELECT Id, Product2Id, Product2.Name, Pricebook2Id, Product2.Name, UnitPrice, CurrencyIsoCode FROM PricebookEntry2" to get your data, which you could massage. I'm just saying the *reporting* feature itself needs a little extra help by way of formula fields.

Comment: Yeah I have really fallen out with the reports today! Thanks for your time - Really appreciate it.